# Return corresponded input type by name as string (string template literal)

Tags: typescript

```
type GenerateArrayKeyType<T extends string, K extends number> = `${T}.${K}`;

type PathImpl<T, Key extends keyof T> =
  Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends readonly unknown[] ?
    GenerateArrayKeyType<Key, 0 | 1>
    : T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
      ? | `${Key}.${PathImpl<T[Key], Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]>> & string}`
        | `${Key}.${Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]> & string}`
      : never
  : never;

type PathImpl2<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T> | keyof T;

type Path<T> = PathImpl2<T> extends string | keyof T ? PathImpl2<T> : keyof T;

type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T>> =
  P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
  ? Key extends keyof T
    ? Rest extends Path<T[Key]>
      ? PathValue<T[Key], Rest>
      : T[Key] extends (infer U)[] 
        ? U
        : never
    : never
  : P extends keyof T
    ? T[P]
    : never;

type DeepNest = {
  test: string[],
}

type Data = {
  array: string[],
  test: string,
  last: string,
  file: File[],
  date: Date[],
  nest: {
    test: string,
  },
  deep: {
    array: DeepNest[]
  }
}

type Pathes = Path<Data>;


function test<T, B extends Path<T> = Path<T>>(name: B): PathValue<T, B> {
    return '' as any;
}


const output = test<Data>('test')
```

I would like to extract type from a string. The above code works with the name look-up `test`, however, the return type will return all types instead of the targeted input type. any suggestions and ideas are appreciated.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201230#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBDYECCTUgNIRABVwIAeQqCAD3XgBMBnKB4JAS3gHMAaKXSmgkZR4AVwC2AI2QA%20KAF4oAAwAkAb0IBfAHTrcmpQG4AUMdCQoABTQALAJLiwAG3K98IAbWEBrAgHsAMyhCOXljKD4CTyEmFnYucKgAfmCAbXcAXWj6JiQIFDo-eCcPUXhveD8Ad3hUrKTEiLhEVHQsHHdiSFJ3XgAGKAAfKABGGUaoAC40zOzhACUIAGM-JDpSOI4eKBR4EHGIw%20Sh5T0CHXVrYHtHF0J0ggzeAFEqJadROjJfEECZx94Pz%20uxAdRkcgAZMxWFsDBMjsNVGp3Bc1K93p9vv4gvdMoDsTs9mCoFDNlw4UcItNEAA3ZCJakQOlIExmEhWWwOZwAJnIoQ51y5d3xvxxcmGQJxrPM0CuNj5CgFNx5CuoXliMK4J0lwWOcqFvJCUygOsI0vZcoAaigPmRCLxLHMmHK%20aFEo61TFTmoOAFkJEQKjff7FiwKcd3E6TQTCBMUqHgFGXbjHgdKSkrTbRHaHiAnlAE2mjtMU3mowAKYNIKAAVQAlHUoPDDika82qSImfTi53mQyrFHTXG0pYMhNGczzRYACIQCBgAByEBYirUiXQLGmZM4dW4xk0phlUGnaBQq8SKGwKBAW81O6e6%20XwFv8R4iScKE30Nfe4iATYTgQNMABiAEQLuiR0GgQHHtBEERIgX5rkcG7Pt%20Wy-lAmiYV887TMhhyXjg0yzvOS4sHUiQHgebIWHKy6Ki6J7ACgMissYARlEswBsEUUCoa4UAAEJJrYCqKMm4LlvAKDiDBQl1tMma2oJQlyARER5MAohIPAUAAOT6TsTAgiYNHGCs8Arn4ojAGAtmKgJzGseW%20mofpdZAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem has little to do with the behavior of your recursive template literal type aliases, and thus for the sake of a producing a minimum reproducible example, let's toss out all of those definitions and just examine the following function and attempt to call it:

```
declare function minTest<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(k: K): T[K];
const ret = minTest<Data>("test"); // string | string[] | etc
```

The generic function `minTest` apparently depends on a type parameter `T` and a related parameter `K` which is some key of `T`, and the return type is the lookup type `T[K]`.  But when you call it with `T` specified as `Data`, and the `k` parameter passed in as `"test"`, you are getting `Data[keyof Data]` out and not `Data["test"]` as you expected.

---

The reason this happens is that TypeScript has no support for *partial type parameter inference* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for a feature request and discussion).  When you call a generic function, either *all* or *none* of its type parameters will be inferred by the compiler.

If you call the function without angle brackets, the compiler will try to infer all the type parameters:

```
minTest(null!); // minTest<unknown, never>()
```

Of course that fails because there's nothing from which to infer `T`.  On the other hand, if you call the function *with* angle brackets, the compiler will *not infer any type parameters for you*:

```
minTest<Data, "test">("test"); // minTest<Data, "test">()
minTest<Data>("test") // minTest<Data, keyof Data>()
```

Note how the [default type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `K extends keyof T = keyof T` does not help you here. Yes, it lets you omit the second type parameter, but you are still not getting *inference* here.  Instead the compiler just uses the default.

It would be nice if there were some syntax like `K extends keyof T = infer` which told the compiler to use inference in this case, but there isn't.

---

In the absence of partial type parameter inference, all you can do is work around it.  The two workarounds I know of here are either to rely on type inference by requiring a *dummy* parameter whose type is the type parameter you'd like to manually specify:

```
declare function minTestDummy<T, K extends keyof T>(dummyT: T, k: K): T[K];

minTestDummy(null! as Data, "test").toUpperCase(); // okay
```

which works but has the drawback that you are giving the function a value of type `T` it doesn't actually need at runtime...

Or, you could use a [*curried*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) generic function with a single type parameter for you to manually specify, which returns a generic function with another type parameter to infer:

```
declare function minTestCurry<T>(): <K extends keyof T>(k: K) => T[K];

minTestCurry<Data>()("test").toUpperCase(); // okay

const dataTest = minTestCurry<Data>();
dataTest("test").toUpperCase(); // okay
```

This also works, but has the drawback that you are calling an extra function at runtime. Personally I prefer currying because it separates the manual part from the inference part, but either way should work.

---

Translating the curried solution back to the code in your question looks like this:

```
declare function test<T>(): <B extends Path<T>>(name: B) => PathValue<T, B>;
const output = test<Data>()('test')
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201230#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFstUAVEAZwwB4SAaeAaXhAA8MRVhz4BrEATxyJ4JeAF5eAoSIB8ACh4AuRgEplJANoMAugG4AUGDyV4cDOMLEylKgBEoGKPIBE7Ss5W74Aem-xKMMQA5vAAPv4YgahBGtphzBhg+vpEpBQYcqjIEBAAhJ4+fqnW1Gg8qDgA7qj0qCAAbiAw8iopVul2DlD0runOLm4YHl6+lmk29o49g-1yrcUdk05yve4qhWMlnVOSgsJLLcn6oJCwCCjo2Hib6bbIBAT8NPRMrOyc3Hx7snLA948kdT0JSqdRaPRtcYYO4PfiZbJ5eBQbhLaZ9FQAOgwOAAqgAHPFNADCyJAcw2AWCyRO0DgSDQmFw+AWlCJyBgMCeJBayiorzYHC4u2k3IUygY6zEMhE4IMLIwbI5TwOcxWM0x2PxhJgJPIZPWo0p0X0oxwMEMxnMwC6JQs8sVnO2y08xxt6TV6KxuIJxNJcwMJt8QeDQeSGH4hPgAHEOE0HCAAIIcqD8BgCEgRkA0ZgCj4RKJBF4595CrIEABGTWlEgABgASADeJAAvhjGwxmzWA+HIwAFBwACwAkgQ8RBnowBMXBZ8pMJueJ9PBJ-xp3mjUEl-AAPwytP8OJvGemEBQYB4CCrsoVaqxHdbmN1GDxpPP1PpzN8gT0AAM8QAjDIW5gvuh65kKABK4BmsAVAbvQUCoPwQHLru4T1g2+6to2-YYMOo7jpooH0AAoiwkDIKAVBfCKWgCNowJzkiSGxDI0oAGT5sEnZbuh7YCNhDZkRRVE0fOdEHox3yIfwrHwJxG48cuyh1I05rKfAqlNN2mbwLh+FjgATDQ1Z6YOI5jhOYmyPE1kkDpfaDiZFj6RZEDGQuR7rpEwS2Uxoi7q5BEedKyh2Q5CD6QAalAEDIFmdB6WuQr6SZ1Zbr2yXcBhxCIE0K6Cbl+VQZQSk7iuWXCvOW67iV5heSlTlEfRKHldFsXxTQEkMfAdWtSB9GVXIRUwPAOIqLENVjcBmkNE0M1aep8DKJlDWzt8JBTZovbaAtc0wBF8C2CAIB4gAcukFgNlugzKBusS0PozZhrpSxXVusBvndPnRA9N3pN9BaPcu0CUIDwTA0gWAQCAygAGLQyAf3Lta7DKJMSMMVudRg-A13Lsut1cdEkPNpDoCnco+ME59Kboyd53pJNy7Pc9+g9pFg4UC5TkHAGNJnPSlxMvAgwmXMvIAEKVal3LyKgUAELD8CS5K0rtXFCX0JLMgGEYqAmDgyAYHixsWGLKoqHIADkgzW60+hAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer is so comprehensive and detailed as well.